# Search for folders that doesn't contain file with a wanted name

Tags: list, powershell, search, directory

I'm working on organizing my movies folders (1500+) and making sure that they all have subtitles in English and Arabic. All my subtitle files have the language code in them (filename.ar.srt) or (filename.en.srt). I want to write a powershell or any other convenient method to list folders that doesn't contain [*.XX.srt] which I can substitute with the language code I'm searching for.

Comment: SO is not a free script request site. What have you tried so far? Show your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing this in the directory containing all your movies' folders :

```
$language = Read-Host "Language to search for"

foreach ($folder in (dir -Directory)) {
    if (-not (Get-ChildItem -Path "$($folder.Name)/*.$language.srt")) {
        "Missing $language subtitle for $($folder.Name)"
    }
}
```